# Syncing custom colors in XCode / Colors in git repo

Tags: ios, xcode, git, colors

When you work with colors in Interface Builder, sometimes it's handy to create your custom set of colors for your brand, so that setting color is just a click away. It's possible to add a new color set in Colors -> Color Palettes, and it works pretty well.

The thing is, this custom color set is not part of your project / repo. It works fine locally on your Mac, but your colleagues may have to set it up again on their machines. If you configure UIColor programmatically, you can have a central place (e.g., a Category for UIColor) in your codebase, which for sure will be in git repo. So the question is, is it possible to do the same for the color set here? Is there a way to sync the custom color set? Where is it actually stored?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The color palette is stored in your `~/Library/Colors`. Once the palette is stored, it is visible for other applications such Photoshop etc.

Comment: thanks for your comment, but i couldn't actually find it in Library->Colors. (i am using El Capitan) any other possible locations? And is there a way of customizing the location?

Comment: Library folder is hidden by default. If you don't see it open the Terminal and type following: `defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles YES`
Unfortunately as far as I know there is no way to change the location.